# Replace values based on JOIN

Tags: sql, hql

Let's say I have two data sets `A` and `B`
[image: photo of datasets A and B]

After left join I should get `FALSE` value for `Y` in table `A` as it doesn't have it in table `B`

Comment: With a LEFT JOIN, you'll get NULL returned from B.  Not sure what you're looking to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your approach, if you intend to get a value of `FALSE` if the value doesn't exist you can check for `NULL` in the name. The example below uses a `CASE` to check for `NULL` and assigns the original value otherwise

```sql
SELECT 
  A.Name,
  CASE 
     WHEN B.Name is NULL THEN 'FALSE'
     ELSE A.Value
  END as Value
FROM
  A
LEFT JOIN
  B on A.Name = B.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know HQL. But in standard SQL that is:

```
select name, name in (select name from b) as value
from a
order by name;
```